# multiple Regression Analysis for categorical and continuous varibles

Tags: regression

I'm conducting a regression analysis between a dependent variable ( continuous) and two independent variable one is categorical ( nominal , yes and no value) and the other is continuous . is the multiple regression analysis the right test ? also should I use the dummy variables here for the categorical variable?

Answer (score 0):

### Introduction

Without understanding the goals of your analysis, I can't say whether multiple regression analysis is the right test or whether you should use dummy variables. However I will try to explain what information a multiple regression analysis will give you and how to interpret dummy variables and you can decide if this is appropriate for your use case.

### Dummy variables

If I've understood correctly it seems as though the categorical variable is binary if it's just yes or no. If it is binary I can't see why there would be a need for a dummy variable, just encoding either yes or no to $0$ or $1$ would be appropriate.

### Multiple regression

In a multiple regression analysis you're modelling the conditional mean dependent variable, lets call that $y$, given your independent variables ($x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ in your case). This is modelled as a linear combination of the independent variables multiplied by some coefficients ($\beta_{1}$ and $\beta_{2}$) plus an intercept term $\beta_{0}$

$$\mathbb{E}[y | x_{1}, x_{2}] = \beta_{0} + x_{1}\beta_{1} + x_{2}\beta_{2}$$

This can be useful if you want to **estimate** the effect that a variable has on your dependent variable. It can be useful if you want to predict future values of $y$ and I'm sure plenty of other things, but these have been my primary uses.

### Interpreting coefficients

After estimating the coefficients from your data, what do they actually tell you?

For the continuous variable the coefficient tells you the expected increase (or decrease if the coefficient is negative) in $y$ given $x_{1}, x_{2}$ per $1$ unit increase in $x_{1}$ **if all other  variables are held constant**

The binary variable interpretation is the same as above but as $x_{2}$ can only take on the values $1$ or $0$ the coefficient tells you how much $\mathbb{E}[y | x_{1}, x_{2}]$ will increase (or decrease) if $x_{2} = 1$

### Prediction

You can also use these coefficients to predict values of $y$ by providing the appropriate values of $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$.

### Example

I don't have any data for this example so I'm just making this up but will hopefully tie the above together.

Let $y$ be the score achieved by a pupil on a text, $x_{1}$ be the number of hours studied and $x_{2}$ be whether they attended an additional class ($1$ if they attended $0$ otherwise. The regression model might look something like

$$\mathbb{E}[test \ score | hours \ studied, extra \ class] = 50 + (0.8)hours \ studied + (20)extra \ class$$

The interpretation is then, if someone didn't study at all and didn't attend an extra class then on average they would score $50$.

If the extra class variable is fixed at either $0$ or $1$ then for every hour studied you would increase your test score by $0.8$

Finally if the hours of study is fixed at some value then attending the extra class would increase your test score by $20$

Now if we wanted to use this model to predict the mean test score for people that study for $10$ hours and attend an extra class we simply input these values into the model
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[test \ score | hours \ studied = 10, extra \ class = 1] &= 50 + (0.8)(10) + (20)(1) \\
&= 78
\end{align*}

### Note on sampling

It is worth noting that any decisions made are heavily dependent on how the data is collected. Be very careful about what decisions are made of the back of this model if you don't have any background in sampling.

For example, if you only collected this data in one school I'd be cautious about inferring that the interpreted coefficients are applicable across all schools. Maybe the extra class was ran by an incredible teacher and the increase in $y$ by $20$ is only applicable to a handful of teachers with their skill. In this case your sample has biased the effect of an extra class.

### Final Remarks

Hopefully this is useful and helps you decide if multiple regression is indeed useful for your use case.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for the elaborate explanation! you are right I'm still learning how to work with Data , the right test here should be multiple regression .